# How to match a set against a set of sets, completely

Tags: mapping, combinatorics, computation-theory, np-complete, set-theory

This problem is similar to the "Exact Hitting Set" problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Exact_hitting_set) but with slightly different constraints.

I am looking for libraries, implementations, or papers that solve the following.

Say I have a set of sets **S**, and is initialized as follows:

```
S = {N, O, P, E};

N = {1, 2, 5}
O = {4, 5}
P = {1, 6, 7}
E = {2, 3, 8}};
```

**S** has n sets, and each subset set is of unknown size. In this example `n = 4`

Now I have another set **X** of size n, which is initialized to:

```
X = {1, 2, 4, 6}
```

What I need to do, is match each element in **X** to one and only one set in **S**.

So **S** should be completely satisfied with all of it's sets mapped to **X** and vice versa.

```
X[0] --> N
X[1] --> E
X[2] --> O
X[3] --> P
```

The main problem I am having is how to deal with the duplicated data with in the sets of **S**. How do I deal with these collisions? And How to implement the algorithm in such a way that is relatively scalable?

If you have any information that could point me in the right direction to solve this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bipartite graph in the following manner:

- For each element in the set **X** create a node in the **U** disjoint set of the graph
- For each subset in the set **S** create a node in the **V** disjoint set of the graph
- If element of **X** in subset of **S** then create an edge between the corresponding nodes in **U** and **V**

Then having the bipartite graph you can solve the problem using [hopcroft karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) to produce the maximum cardinality matching.(`O(|E|sqrt(V))`)

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly the direction I want to go with this.